# Find IDs in one file that are not in another

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

I have two files:

**abc.txt**

```
abcd
xyz
pqrs
```

**mno.txt**

```
zzon
mkno
abcd
```

- I want to check whether "abcd" is there in file **mno.txt**.
- It is not necessary that if "abcd" is first in **abc.txt** , it will also first in **mno.txt**.
- There is thousands of such id's in both files.
- I want to also check how many id's are not in **mno.txt** which are in **abc.txt**.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 19):

If your goal is to find common or uncommon lines, `comm` would be my go-to command here.

It compares two files and shows —in three columns— lines that are unique to file 1, lines that are unique to file 2 and lines that appear in both files, respectively.  You can pass it flags to suppress any of this output too. Eg `comm -1 file1 file2` will suppress the first column, the things unique to file1. `comm -12 file1 file2` would only show things in both files.

There's one big caveat: the input must be sorted. We can work around this.

This will show you everything in abc which isn't in mno:

```
comm -23 <(sort abc.txt) <(sort mno.txt)
```

And you can pipe that into `wc -l` to get a count.

---

The reason I go with `comm` is that once the files are sorted, side-by-side comparison is computationally really simple. If you're dealing with millions of these, that will make a difference.

This can be demonstrated with a couple of mock files. I have a fairly fast computer so to show the difference between approaches, I need quite a mammoth sample set. I've gone to 10 million 10-char strings per file.

```
$ cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -10000000 > abc.txt
$ cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -10000000 > mno.txt

$ time comm -23 <(sort abc.txt) <(sort mno.txt) | wc -l
... 0m10.653s

$ time grep -Fcxv -f abc.txt mno.txt
... 0m23.920s

$ time grep -Fcwv -f abc.txt mno.txt
... 0m40.313s

$ time awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++};NR!=FNR && a[$0]' abc.txt  mno.txt | wc -l
... 0m12.161s
```

The sorting is what takes most of the time in mine. If we pretend that abc.txt is static, we can pre-sort it and that makes future comparisons much faster:

```
$ sort abc.txt abc-sorted.txt
$ time comm -23 abc-sorted.txt <(sort mno.txt) | wc -l
... 0m7.426s
```

You might look at these and consider a few seconds irrelevant but I have to highlight that these are running on a high end machine. If you wanted to do this on a (eg) Raspberry Pi 3, you'll be looking at much slower turnarounds and the difference will increase to a point it actually matters.

Answer (score 7):

to get a list :

```
grep -Fwf abc.txt mno.txt
```

it gives you something similar to:

```
abcd
abcd
zef
```

if you want to just get a unique list then use it like:

```
grep -Fwf abc.txt mno.txt | sort | uniq
```

and to get the counts:

```
grep -Fcwv -f abc.txt mno.txt
```

---

- `-F` means: interpret PATTERN as a list of  fixed  strings instead  of  regular expressions.
- `-f` obtain patterns from FILE which going to be `abc.txt`.
- we look into `mno.txt` for patterns
- `-c` Count the number of matches
- `-w` Only look for "whole words": the matching substring must  either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character. Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character. Word-constituent  characters  are  letters, digits, and the underscore.
- `-v` Reverse the search

Comment: If the OP wants a *count* of *non* matches, shouldn't that be more like `grep -cxvFf abc.txt mno.txt` ?

Comment: Just saw it :D ... your always here to save me :D

Comment: FYI the `fgrep`, `egrep` alternates are supposedly deprecated (in favor of `grep -F`, `grep -E` - although I'm not sure anyone believes they will ever go away

Comment: Is it necessary to use `-x` when using `-F` ?

Comment: It depends what the OP wants to count exactly - e.g. if mno.txt contains `abcdef` should that count as a match or a non-match to `abcd`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right ...

Comment: @steeldriver `-w` might be better in case there are other things on the line (whitespace in one file missing from the other, for example).

Comment: FWIW, moving to -w doubles the time it takes to run.

Comment: @Oli yes, that makes sense but it is more correct if (big if) the files can differ in whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

We could use awk to do the job by passing two files, first the pattern file, then the file we want to check. When we're reading first file, we know that `NR==FNR` and at that time we can read lines into array. When `NR!=FNR` we check if array for such line is set.

```
$ cat abc.txt                                                      
abcd
xyz
pqrs
$ cat mno.txt                                                      
zzon
xyz
mkno
abcd
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++};NR!=FNR && a[$0]' abc.txt  mno.txt         
xyz
abcd
```

Conversely, we can negate the pattern to print those lines that aren't in `abc.txt`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++};NR!=FNR && ! a[$0]' abc.txt  mno.txt       
zzon
mkno
```

And if we want to print the count of those we can employ `sort` and `wc`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++};NR!=FNR && ! a[$0]' abc.txt  mno.txt | sort -u | wc -l         
2
```

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way around. As far as I understand the question, OP wants to calculate the (size of) the set difference of `abc.txt` − `mno.txt` which is `{xyz, pqrs}`.

Answer (score 2):

If either of the word lists is unsorted it would be faster to use an efficient set data structure to remember the common words.

### Python

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as minuend_file:
    minuend = frozenset(map(str.rstrip, minuend_file))
with open(sys.argv[2]) as subtrahend_file:
    subtrahend = frozenset(map(str.rstrip, subtrahend_file))

difference = minuend - subtrahend
#print(*difference, sep='\n') # This prints the content of the set difference
print(len(difference)) # This prints the magnitude of the set difference
```

Usage:

```
python3 set-difference.py abc.txt mno.txt
```

### Python (more efficient)

If you want to save a little memory for intermediary storage and run time you can use this slightly more difficult to understand program:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as minuend_file:
    minuend = set(map(str.rstrip, minuend_file))
with open(sys.argv[2]) as subtrahend_file:
    subtrahend = map(str.rstrip, subtrahend_file)
    minuend.difference_update(subtrahend)
    difference = minuend
    del minuend

#print(*difference, sep='\n') # This prints the content of the set difference
print(len(difference)) # This prints the magnitude of the set difference
```

#### Performance

Given `abc.txt` and `mno.txt` with 1 mio unsorted lines of 10 random ASCII digit characters each (see Oli's answer for the set-up):

```
$ time python3 set-difference.py abc.txt mno.txt
user    0m10.453s
```

vs.

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=C
$ time sort abc.txt > abc_sorted.txt
user    0m10.652s
$ time sort mno.txt > mno_sorted.txt
user    0m10.767s
$ time comm -23 abc_sorted.txt mno_sorted.txt | wc -l
9989882
user    0m1.600s
```

total: 23 seconds